# Why svn commit changes timestamps?

Tags: svn, timestamp

I am working on C++ project under SVN version control. Here is my typical workflow:

- do some changes in working copy
- build & test project
- commit

After last step all timestamps of commited files are changed to current time. This is inconvenient because all parts of the project that depend on these files will be rebuilt once again although their content did not change after commit (only timestamps).

- Why this behavior can be useful?
- Can I configure svn to disable it?

Comment: which svn-client do you use? in which OS?

Comment: Do your files have the svn:keyword property set?

Comment: Which timestmamps?  Last access or last modification time?

Comment: I have the same effect on Linux, I think answer 1 is right (svn:keywords).

Comment: Yes, I have set `svn:keywords` to `Id Rev`. I don't think, I can remove them as they are used in cpp and h files.

Comment: @ks1322: Then you should expect your modification time stamp to change, because your file **does** **change** on every commit. Remove the keywords or live with the recompile.

Comment: Ok, I have got it. Files are actually modified after commit because new revision number is written to file - this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, this behaviour is not expected from SVN clients. However, the svn:keywords property has this side-effect (since replacing the property changes the file's timestamp). When you don't need keywords (they are rarely used in C++ projects), you should check if the svn:keywords property is set and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use TSVN, you can change Settings - General - Set file dates to checkbox
- If you use CLI, but still on Windows `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\Tigris.org​\Subversion\Config​\miscellany` "use-commit-times" key (yes|no)
- [If you use any other OS](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) - you have to find and edit Subversion config file and change as you want `#use-commit-times = yes' key

SVN properties (any) are slightly related to timestamp question